# Getting 505 response from console and do something with div

Tags: angularjs

What i am getting is 500 error on console,

[image]

what i need is to get this response from console and show a div for this i have done this but it is not working

```
error(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 500) {
        //showing div here
    }
}
```

Please let me know the correct way to resolve this

the whole code for refrence

```
geniedoc.controller('uploadAppPrescriptionController', ['$scope','Upload','$timeout','MyService','$window',function($scope, Upload, $timeout,MyService,$window) {

    $scope.isProcessing = false;
    $scope.hidemultiLoader = false;
    $scope.reportmultiLoader = false;
    var counter=0;
    $scope.uploadchoices = [{id: counter,
                      uploadedFile:''
                       }];

     $scope.addNewUpload = function($event) {
         counter++;
    $scope.uploadchoices.push({'id': counter,
                           uploadedFile:''
                         });

console.log("Adding uploadedFile=>"+angular.toJson($scope.uploadchoices));
     }

  $scope.multiUploadFiles=function(appointmentId,patientEmailId){
      $scope.isProcessing = true;
        $scope.dynamic = 0;
        $scope.hidemultiLoader = true;
       console.log($scope.uploadchoices);
var docChoice=null;
var files=[];
for(var i=0;i<$scope.uploadchoices.length;i++){
files.push($scope.uploadchoices[i].uploadedFile);
    console.log(files[i]);
}
               Upload.upload({  method: 'POST',
                        file:files,
                        url: '/GenieDoc/api/user/upload-prescription?file='+files+ '&appointmentId=' +appointmentId + '&patientId=' + patientEmailId + '&docChoice=' + docChoice
                    }).progress(function(evt) {
                var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                $scope.dynamic = progressPercentage;
                // alert(progressPercentage);
                $scope.uploadedFileName = evt.config.file.name;
                console.log("uploadedFileName:"+$scope.uploadedFileName);
                $scope.log = 'progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% '; // +evt.config.file.name
                // + '\n' + $scope.log;
            console.log("file process");

            if(progressPercentage==100)
            {
            var iEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#pers' ) );
     iEl.remove();
            }


            }).success(function(response) {
                         console.log("multiUploadFiles:=>"+angular.toJson(response));
            $timeout(function() { 
                            $scope.getDoctorPreviousAppointments();
                            $scope.getPatientReports();
                                },3000);
                   //$window.location.reload();
                   $scope.hidemultiLoader=false;
                    }).error(function(response, status) {
                         if (response.status === 500) {
                   alert(dadasdada);
                }

                    });
    }
```

**provided the whole code for reference but i only need to get the 500 error from the console and do something with that is that possible?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: We need a little more context, provide the POST call

Comment: have you tried console.log(response) in the error catcher? it may give you an insight as to what obj is stored as the parameter. Secondly, what is this promise chained onto?

Comment: Another note, is that `success` and `error` are deprecated, so use the standard promise function `then`

Comment: provided the whole code for reference but i only need to get the 500 error from the console and do something with that is that possible?

Comment: You could write an Http Interceptor to get the request data before you retrieve it in the controller, and deal with the 500 there.

Comment: so there is no other way to get server response from "console" and do somehting with it?

Comment: Your error handler already has a `status` argument.

Comment: Are you actually saying that you want the error that has been outputted to the console ??

Answer (score 0):

It could be useful to know how you create your call, but if I'm working with my calls: it should be something like:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    //Do what you need to do on success
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
     if (500 === response.status) {
        //Do what you need to do on a 500-response
     }
  });
```

Comment: can it also fetch the 500 error from the console? and not from the specified url